# Как получить текущее state внутри выполнения функций

Tags: reactjs, state

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Admin extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputAuthor: '',
      inputText: ''
    };
    this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
  }
  updateInputValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
      inputAuthor: evt.target.value,
      inputText: evt.target.value
    });
  }
  BtnClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const author =  this.state.inputAuthor;
    const text = this.state.inputText;
    console.log(author + ' ' + text);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form className="add">
        <label>Автор:</label>
        <input type="text" className="add__author" value="123" onChange={this.updateInputValue} />
        <label>Новость:</label>
        <textarea value="123" className="add__author" onChange={this.updateInputValue} ></textarea>
        <button className="add__btn" onClick={this.BtnClick}>Опубликовать</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Admin;
```

ругается на эти две строки 
const author =  this.state.inputAuthor;
const text = this.state.inputText;

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что дело в контексте. Если сделать BtnClick стрелочной функцией или же написать в конструкторе `this.BtnClick = this.BtnClick.bind(this)`, всё должно заработать.

Лучше всего пользоваться стрелочными функциями, чтобы постоянно не привязывать контекст.